# Включен ли Caps Lock или нет на сайте?

Tags: javascript

Можно узнать на сайте, включен ли Caps Lock или нет?

Comment: [Как на Javascript узнать состояние "Caps Lock"][1]


  [1]: http://www.tigir.com/capslockdetect.htm

Comment: @vv2cc: приведённый способ работает только для букв и только _после_ нажатия клавиш. А капслок в некоторых раскладках на windows (например, в немецкой, если я не ошибаюсь) действует и на цифры.

Comment: @VladD, "capitals lock" - "фиксация прописных букв". Ну ни в одной из раскладок с клавишей "Caps Lock" нет необходимости выполнять такого рода фиксацию для цифр - неудобно это. Была когда-то кнопка "Shift Lock", но это времена печатных машинок и логика у нее другая.

Comment: @Равнодушный: вы в самом деле пробовали немецкую раскладку на винде, или говорите из общих соображений?

Comment: @Равнодушный, @Vlad. У меня немецкая раскладка клавиатуры, подтверждаю, включенный caps lock действует на цифры. 1,2,3 = !"§

Comment: @Vlad, у меня есть немецкая клавиатура раскладки "QWERTZ" от IBM. И на ней "Caps Lock" работает именно так, как и должен. А тот эффект, что Вы наблюдаете на некоторых вариантах раскладки от Microsoft - это как раз те самые раскладки с кнопкой "Shift Lock" от популярных для тех или иных стран печатных машинок.

Comment: @Равнодушный: работа капслока зависит, конечно, не от клавиатуры, а от ОС. Вы пробовали стандартную немецкую раскладку на винде или на другой ОС? Вот @Павел Азанов подтверждает мои опасения. То, что такое поведение -- наследие прошлого, конечно, интересная историческая подробность. Так и раскладка QWERTY/Z -- тоже наследие эпохи печатных машинок. Итак, возвращаясь к началу дискуссии: по факту действие капслока не обязательно ограничено буквами.

Comment: Эх... Раскладку по умолчанию определяет драйвер клавиатуры. Драйверов с клавишей "Shift Lock" полно, а вот клавиатур с ней Вы у современных пользователей не найдете. Так что наличие раскладок, в которых "Caps Lock" включает режим "Shift Lock" - это просто старое ПО, и не стоит на это обращать внимание.

Comment: @Равнодушный: к сожалению, сложно заставить юзера не пользоваться родной раскладкой виндовой по умолчанию, даже если она плоха и нелогична. Наша цель ведь сделать юзеру комфортно, отталкиваясь от его настроек. Если юзер фактически пользуется Shift Lock вместо Caps Lock (из-за софта), надо жить и с этим.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Учитывая дискуссию в комментариях к вопросу, вот вариант, который определяет включен ли Caps Lock даже если нажата цифра (**только в случае если Caps Lock имеет эффект!**):

```
$('#txtTest').on('keydown', function(e) {
    $(this).data('_lastKey', e.which);
});
$('#txtTest').on('keypress', function(e) {

    var lastKey = +$(this).data('_lastKey');

    if(lastKey < 47 || lastKey > 90) return true;

    var letter    = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    var upper     = letter.toUpperCase();
    var lower     = letter.toLowerCase();
    var isNumeric = lastKey >= 48 && lastKey <= 57;

    var caps = false;

    if(isNumeric)
        caps = (lastKey == e.which && e.shiftKey) || (lastKey != e.which && !e.shiftKey);
    else if( (letter === upper && !e.shiftKey) || (letter === lower && e.shiftKey) )
        caps = !isNumeric;

    //alert(caps);
});
```

Единственный выход это предварительно отлавливать событие `keydown` и сохранять нажатую клавишу.

Демо: http://jsfiddle.net/xH8vC/10/

Оформил как плагин к jQuery: [jquery.capsChecker](https://github.com/azanov/jquery.capsChecker)

Comment: Ну, ваш код ловит капслок на цифрах в немецкой раскладке, но не в английской. Хотя, возможно, это и хорошо: детектируется только потенциально проблемная ситуация.

+1.

Comment: да, для варианта когда капс есть, но эффекта нет, думаю к сожалению нет решения. но это не так страшно.

Comment: Ага, думаю, что проблема обычно именно в невидимом переключении символов при вводе, например, пароля. Если переключения нет, и проблемы нет.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  /* Работает в Chrome 31+, Firefox 15+, Internet Explorer 9+, Opera -, Safari (Webkit) - */
  var caps = event.getModifierState && event.getModifierState('CapsLock');
  document.getElementById('capsTest').innerHTML = caps ? 'Капс нажат' : 'Капс не нажат';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w2vk0bzL/

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать JQuery.

```
$('#example').keypress(function(e) { 
    var s = String.fromCharCode( e.which );
    if ( s.toUpperCase() === s && s.toLowerCase() !== s && !e.shiftKey ) {
        alert('caps is on');
    }
});
```

*Взял со StackOwerflow*

Либо можете воспользоваться какой-нибудь уже написанной библиотекой. [Вот](http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/detecting-the-caps-lock-key/) например.

Ну и в добавление. Я не считаю возможным получить состояние капслока до того, как пользователь начнет вводить текст.

Comment: И ваш способ тоже работает только для букв. Кроме того, он не поймает капслок + шифт. Почему бы не использовать модуль на flash?

Comment: Не могу понять почему flash так боятся, либо по неопытности, либо эффект биомассы, когда начал изучать эту тему (певерхностно) понравилось, что большинство проблем решаются очень просто. Слова в поддержку слов @VlaD =)