# Как сделать скрипт для проверки, что включен Caps Lock и включена русская раскладка

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

Нужен скрипт, который будет проверять инпут для ввода пароля и в случае, если человек пишет с включенным Caps Lock или на русской раскладке выводить всплывающее сообщение. Примерно реализацию я представляю, но в js не силен, вдруг есть решения лучше или уже готовые. Заранее спасибо.

PS

В итоге у меня есть два лейбла, которые я скрываю display:none; через css

но скрипт, но что-то не фурычит)

```
 document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    var capsLockEnabled = event.getModifierState && event.getModifierState('CapsLock');
    if (capsLockEnabled = true) {
        document.getElementById('capsWarning').style.display ='block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('capsWarning').style.display ='none';
    }
});

document.getElementById("password").addEventListener("keydown", function() {
    if (/^[а-яА-Я]+$/.test(this.value)) {
        document.getElementById("langWarning").style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("langWarning").style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/task/capslock-warning-field

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Включен ли Caps Lock или нет на сайте?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/179050/%d0%92%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%bb%d0%b8-caps-lock-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lenskyuser/xH8vC/28/

Comment: Спасибо, но эти варианты у меня есть и тут нет ничего про проверку на раскладку.

Comment: исправь вопрос таким способом что бы был ваш пример и что бы ясна была суть вопроса ...

Comment: По поводу раскладки посмотрите на [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8892715/1878432) ответ. Может Вам лучше проверять доступный(или недоступный) диапазон символов, например, как [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2257084/1878432).

Comment: @МаксимЛенский изменил.

Comment: пока не разбираясь вижу ошибку в проверке if (capsLockEnabled = true), здесь вы присваиваете значение, оно будет работать всегда. При проверке (нестрогой) ставьте двойной знак равенства ==

Comment: И ещё не совсем понятна конструкция var capsLockEnabled = event.getModifierState && event.getModifierState('CapsLock');

Comment: уместнее проверка if(event.getModifierState('shift') == true || event.getModifierState('CapsLock')==true)

Comment: Кроме того событие прослушивается для всего документа. Вам же необходимо слушать только в поле введения пароля? И, как заметил @МаксимЛенский, скажите какие символы разрешены в поле пароля? Понятно пока, что только маленькие латинские. Как насчёт цифр и других, и спецсимволов?

Comment: @АлексейДрижаков итоговый скрипт такой.

Comment: @АлексейДрижаков https://jsfiddle.net/2tnLmg8n/3/

Comment: Отлично! Можно порадоваться...